# Is the foobar:finished:context: method of UIView animations delegate really giving a BOOL for finished?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

Althoug I read everywhere that the method signature has a BOOL for finished, I do never get a false. It is always true. And now the strange thing:

When I NSLog that out with %d, it is always either 32 or 40. Other BOOLs I have are either 1 or 0. That makes no sense. So: Not a bool, right?

What's that instead, really?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method signature for the did stop delegate selector is

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context;
```

The `finished` parameter is an `NSNumber` that wraps up a boolean value. In Objective-C and other languages, any non-zero value is considered true (even negative numbers).

You can call `[finished boolValue]` on the NSNumber instance to get a true `BOOL`, `YES` or `NO` value.

The `finished` boolean value will be `NO` if the animation was cancelled or otherwise interrupted before completing it's full animation. If the animation ran through fully, then it will be `YES`.

From the docs:

> **finished**
>
> An `NSNumber` object containing a Boolean value. The value is `YES` if the animation ran to completion before it stopped or `NO` if it did not.